# How to generate an "id" on WEB google App Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications

I have this script to insert data into the spreadsheet.

I created a way to generate an ID with the value of the date and time, the problem that is too large

example: `E1567301439829`

Is there any way I can generate a unique and short ID for each record?

I would like to leave an id like: `E001, E002, E003....`

Link Ws: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OokFvWCx-ROkhaLP1nYQPDAu8zgCTeizHHq0ABnBL0A/edit#gid=0

```js
 function doGet(e){
  Logger.log(e.parameter);
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index");
  
}

function registrar(name){
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OokFvWCx-ROkhaLP1nYQPDAu8zgCTeizHHq0ABnBL0A/edit#gid=0"
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Página1");
  
  
  var date = new Date().valueOf();
  var idEntrada = 'E' + date
  
  ws.appendRow([idEntrada,name]);
  
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    
    
    <label>Nome</label><input type="text" id="nome">
    
    <button id="btn">Registrar</button>
    
    <script>
    
    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",salvar);
    
    function salvar(){
    
       var campoNome = document.getElementById("nome").value;
       
       google.script.run.registrar(campoNome);
       
       document.getElementById("nome").value = "";
    }
    
    
    </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to modify `E1567301439829` to "a unique and short ID". If my understanding is correct, can I ask you about the sample values you want?

Comment: How is the current ID too large?

Comment: I would like to leave an id like: E001, E002, E003

Comment: @Herohtar, Actually my id is generated like this: E1567301439829, really good if I gave, stop generating a sequential id E001, E002, E003 ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

### Pattern 1:

If each row is appended using `appendRow()`, how about this modification?

#### From:

```
var date = new Date().valueOf();
var idEntrada = 'E' + date
```

#### To:

```
var idEntrada = 'E' + ('00' + ws.getLastRow()).slice(-3);
```

### Pattern 2:

If there are several empty rows, how about this modification?

#### From:

```
var date = new Date().valueOf();
var idEntrada = 'E' + date
```

#### To:

```
var idEntrada = 'E' + ('00' + (ws.getRange("A2:A").getValues().filter(String).length + 1)).slice(-3);
```

### Note:

- In your script, it seems that you are using Web Apps. In this case, when you modified your script, please redeploy Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to Web Apps. If you are using Web Apps as the developer mode, this can be ignored.

### References:

- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow())
- [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

If I misunderstood your question and this wat not the direction you want, I apologize.